# Why `minicom` append the `0xOD` character to serial text message?

Tags: serial-port, newlines, minicom, kermit

I have a serial device attached to my PC's usb port, and get /dev/ttyUSB0. Then I run `minicom` on it, and run `strace -p <minicom pid>` to monitor minicom's activity.

I found that, when I send text to /dev/ttyUSB0, every text message was appended an `\r` character, i.e. `0x0D`.

I have done the same work using `kermit` and found the same result.

So my first doubt is: why these tools append the `\r` character?

Also, I know that in Unix ecosystem, `\n` is used for new line character, why these serial tools append `\r` but not `\n`? This is my second doubt.

I have googled "minicom send carriage return", "minicom add carriage return", "minicom carriage return", but find no result, and it seems that the content of `minicom` in internet is sometimes rare...

At last, please allow me to issue my last question: if `minicom` still an active project, I find it not update from Dec, 2013 from [its mainpage](https://alioth.debian.org/projects/minicom/), but kermit project is updated more recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main use of minicom during its heyday was for talking to modems which understood the [Hayes command set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) (AT commands). AT commands are terminated by carriage return. It was convenient to be able to type `ATDT5550123` <kbd>Enter</kbd> and have the correct command terminator sent to the modem.

Comment: Thanks very much! So does this apply to Kermit, too?